# How do I send library alerts to random submitters?

Tags: alert

I don't control access to the library, so the submitter could be someone I don't know and therefore wouldn't be in my alerts list. Is there a way for the list to reply to submitters without each one being explicitly entered?

Answer (score 0):

If the alert should go to the original submitter when somebody else changes something, then a simple workflow should be sufficient.